# query for select fields from two tables joined with pivot lave_mysql_laravel query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel-9, laravel-query-builder

I have two tables

1.PURCHASE TABLE

| id | Country | Medicine | Quantity | Purchase date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Canada | Aspirin | 9 | 26/01/2022 14:16:59 |
| 1 | Canada | VitaminD | 10 | 19/07/2021 14:16:59 |
| 2 | Usa | Calcium | 4 | 19/06/2021 14:16:59 |
| 3 | Canada | VitaminC | 8 | 06/08/2022 14:16:59 |
| 4 | Argentina | Calcium | 10 | 05/12/2021 14:16:59 |

2.PRICES TABLE

| id | Country | Year | Medicine | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | USA | 2020 | Aspirin | 14 |
| 1 | Canada | 2020 | Aspirin | 18 |
| 2 | Mexico | 2020 | Aspirin | 10 |
| 3 | Brasil | 2020 | Aspirin | 11 |
| 4 | Argentina | 2021 | Aspirin | 18 |

3. PRICE_PURCHASE TABLE (PIVOT TABLE)

| price_id | purchase_id |
| --- | --- |

I want to select purchase.country, purchas.medicine, purchase.quantity from purchases table and prices.price from prices table. My pivot table is empty, how can I do the query (mysql and with laravel query builder too) to catch all this fields, (filtering prices.price that matches with puchases table country, medicine and purchase data)

Thank you very much for you time

Comment: Try with this query => `DB::table('purchases')
            ->join('prices', function ($join) {
                $join->on('purchases.country', '=', 'prices.country')
                     ->on(DB::raw('YEAR(purchases.purchase_date)'), '=', 'prices.year')
                     ->on('purchases.medicine', '=', 'prices.medicine');
            })
            ->select('purchases.country', 'purchases.medicine', 'purchases.quantity', 'prices.price')
            ->get();`

Comment: Code is added as answer for others too.

Answer (score 1):

For that your db query for Laravel is like:

```
DB::table('purchases')->join('prices', function ($join) {
            $join->on('purchases.country', '=', 'prices.country')->on(DB::raw('YEAR(purchases.purchase_date)'), '=', 'prices.year')->on('purchases.medicine', '=', 'prices.medicine');
})->select('purchases.country', 'purchases.medicine','purchases.quantity', 'prices.price')->get();
```

Comment: I don´t know why, but this query sometimes duplicates items... the crud is working perfectly and  everthing is istored in database without error.... but this query sometimes generetes duplicates... is there another option?